# Outlook (exchange) Automatic sending a sequence of eMails (autoresponder)

Tags: exchange, outlook, auto-reply

Hoping someone knows of a solution, ideally integrated with outlook or exchange server, something that will keep a list of users email addresses, and automatically send them a time sequence of emails.    In the affiliate marketing world, this is known as an autoresponder, though I am NOT looking for 'out of office'.

Basically, I need a user to be able to enter a list of emails (and add new emails in the future for new hires).   This autoresponder would then send a series of emails, but on a timed basis.   For example, as soon as the email address is added, the first email can be sent.   After a week, the second email, two weeks and the third email will go out, etc. until the series is complete.

In our case, this is intended to be used as a training reminder system for employees.  The first email might welcome the employee to the company, and introduce them to the series of training emails.   Then the weekly emails act as a reminder to continue their training each week, giving them a link or similar.

I believe there is a dedicated piece of software out there to do this, but not sure if there are any others, or hopefully one of outlook/exchange?

Answer (score 0):

Try 'Campaign Monitor'. They're mainly for mass marketing mailings, but you can also set them to function as an auto-reply service.

They charge per email sent on the mass mailings, I wouldn't know what they charge for the auto-reply functionality.